SwiftUI List Auto-Scrolls to Top on Data Loading
I'm encountering two issues with List in SwiftUI, and I've attached a GIF and image for reference:
Auto-Scrolling to Top on Data Update:
Whenever I update my data (e.g., reloading or modifying the list), the List automatically scrolls to the top. I would prefer it to remain at its current scroll position. How can I prevent this behavior and keep the scroll position stable?
Swipe Actions Affect All Items:
I've implemented swipe actions using .swipeActions on my List. However, when I swipe any item, the swipe actions seem to apply to all rows in the list instead of just the one I interacted with. How can I limit the swipe actions to only the specific item being swiped?
Additional Information:
I'm using a List wrapped in a NavigationView.
Data updates dynamically as it's fetched from a remote API.
For swipe actions, I’m using the .swipeActions modifier.


 private var historySection: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            if viewModel.isLoading || viewModel.isLoadingMore {
                ForEach(0..<3, id: \.self) { _ in
                    SkeletonHistorySectionView()
                }
            } else {
                ForEach(groupedItems, id: \.key) { date, items in
                    VStack(spacing: 0) {
                        Text(viewModel.dateFormatter.string(from: date))
                            .font(.footnote)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .padding(.leading)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .padding(.top)

                        ForEach(items) { item in
                            HistoryRow(item: item, dateFormatter: viewModel.dateFormatter, timeFormatter: viewModel.timeFormatter, categoryDictionary: categoryDictionary, accountDictionary: accountDictionary, viewModel: viewModel)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    selectedItem = item
                                    showingDetailSheet.toggle()
                                }
                                .swipeActions {
                                    Button {
                                       //TEST
                                    } label: {
                                        Label("TEST.", systemImage: "pencil")
                                    }
                                    .tint(.accentColor)
                                }
                        }
                        .padding(.bottom, 8)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

struct HistoryRow: View {
    let item: HistoryItem
    let dateFormatter: DateFormatter
    let timeFormatter: DateFormatter
    let categoryDictionary: [Int: Category]
    let accountDictionary: [Int: Account]
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: HistoryViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: item.iconName)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)

            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(item.title)
                    .font(.headline)
                Text(mainAccountName(for: item.accountId ?? 0))
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
            Spacer()
            Text(formattedAmount)
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(item.type == "expense" ? .red : .green)
        }
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .padding(.top)
        .padding(.bottom)
    }
    
    func mainAccountName(for accountId: Int) -> String {
        guard let account = accountDictionary[accountId] else { return "Не указан" }
        return account.name
    }
    
    private var formattedAmount: String {
        let amount = item.amount
        return NumberFormatterHelper.formatNumberWithSign(item.type == "expense" ? -amount : amount, currency: viewModel.selectedCurrency)
    }
}



func loadMoreHistoryData(reset: Bool = false, reportMonth: String, reportCategoryId: Int = 0) async {
        if isLoadingMore { return }

        isLoadingMore = true
        defer { isLoadingMore = false }

        if reset {
            currentPage = 1
            historyItems = []
            isAllDataLoaded = false
        }

        do {
            let (newItems, totalIncome, totalExpenses) = try await dataService.getRecentTransactions(page: currentPage, size: pageSize, reportMonth: reportMonth, reportCategoryId: reportCategoryId)
            
            // Сохраняем статистику
            self.totalIncome = totalIncome
            self.totalExpenses = totalExpenses
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.historyItems.append(contentsOf: newItems)
                self.currentPage += 1
                if newItems.count < self.pageSize {
                    self.isAllDataLoaded = true
                }
            }
        } catch {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.errorMessage = error.localizedDescription
            }
        }
    }


 func loadMoreHistoryForCategory(reportMonth: String, selectedCategoryId: Int) async {
        guard !isLoadingMore, !isAllDataLoaded else { return }

        isLoadingMore = true
        defer { isLoadingMore = false }

        do {
            let (newItems, totalIncome, totalExpenses) = try await dataService.getHistoryForCategory(page: currentPage, size: pageSize, reportMonth: reportMonth, reportCategoryId: selectedCategoryId)
            
            // Сохраняем статистику
            self.totalIncome = totalIncome
            self.totalExpenses = totalExpenses
            
            if newItems.count < pageSize {
                isAllDataLoaded = true
            }

            if !newItems.isEmpty {
                historyItems.append(contentsOf: newItems)
                currentPage += 1
            }
        } catch {
            print("Ошибка подгрузки истории для категории \(selectedCategoryId) за месяц \(reportMonth): \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }


 private var historySection: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            if viewModel.isLoading || viewModel.isLoadingMore {
                ForEach(0..<3, id: \.self) { _ in
                    SkeletonHistorySectionView()
                }
            } else {
                ForEach(groupedItems, id: \.key) { date, items in
                    VStack(spacing: 0) {
                        Text(viewModel.dateFormatter.string(from: date))
                            .font(.footnote)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .padding(.leading)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .padding(.top)

                        ForEach(items) { item in
                            HistoryRow(item: item, dateFormatter: viewModel.dateFormatter, timeFormatter: viewModel.timeFormatter, categoryDictionary: categoryDictionary, accountDictionary: accountDictionary, viewModel: viewModel)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    selectedItem = item
                                    showingDetailSheet.toggle()
                                }
                                .swipeActions {
                                    Button {
                                       //TEST
                                    } label: {
                                        Label("TEST.", systemImage: "pencil")
                                    }
                                    .tint(.accentColor)
                                }
                        }
                        .padding(.bottom, 8)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

struct HistoryRow: View {
    let item: HistoryItem
    let dateFormatter: DateFormatter
    let timeFormatter: DateFormatter
    let categoryDictionary: [Int: Category]
    let accountDictionary: [Int: Account]
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: HistoryViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: item.iconName)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)

            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(item.title)
                    .font(.headline)
                Text(mainAccountName(for: item.accountId ?? 0))
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
            Spacer()
            Text(formattedAmount)
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(item.type == "expense" ? .red : .green)
        }
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .padding(.top)
        .padding(.bottom)
    }
    
    func mainAccountName(for accountId: Int) -> String {
        guard let account = accountDictionary[accountId] else { return "Не указан" }
        return account.name
    }
    
    private var formattedAmount: String {
        let amount = item.amount
        return NumberFormatterHelper.formatNumberWithSign(item.type == "expense" ? -amount : amount, currency: viewModel.selectedCurrency)
    }
}



func loadMoreHistoryData(reset: Bool = false, reportMonth: String, reportCategoryId: Int = 0) async {
        if isLoadingMore { return }

        isLoadingMore = true
        defer { isLoadingMore = false }

        if reset {
            currentPage = 1
            historyItems = []
            isAllDataLoaded = false
        }

        do {
            let (newItems, totalIncome, totalExpenses) = try await dataService.getRecentTransactions(page: currentPage, size: pageSize, reportMonth: reportMonth, reportCategoryId: reportCategoryId)
            
            // Сохраняем статистику
            self.totalIncome = totalIncome
            self.totalExpenses = totalExpenses
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.historyItems.append(contentsOf: newItems)
                self.currentPage += 1
                if newItems.count < self.pageSize {
                    self.isAllDataLoaded = true
                }
            }
        } catch {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.errorMessage = error.localizedDescription
            }
        }
    }


 func loadMoreHistoryForCategory(reportMonth: String, selectedCategoryId: Int) async {
        guard !isLoadingMore, !isAllDataLoaded else { return }

        isLoadingMore = true
        defer { isLoadingMore = false }

        do {
            let (newItems, totalIncome, totalExpenses) = try await dataService.getHistoryForCategory(page: currentPage, size: pageSize, reportMonth: reportMonth, reportCategoryId: selectedCategoryId)
            
            // Сохраняем статистику
            self.totalIncome = totalIncome
            self.totalExpenses = totalExpenses
            
            if newItems.count < pageSize {
                isAllDataLoaded = true
            }

            if !newItems.isEmpty {
                historyItems.append(contentsOf: newItems)
                currentPage += 1
            }
        } catch {
            print("Ошибка подгрузки истории для категории \(selectedCategoryId) за месяц \(reportMonth): \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }


Presumably when your data is loaded you are switching from the SkeletonHistorySectionView to the actual views - Because the section ids are changing, it isn't possible for SwiftUI to maintain the scroll position - The section that was displayed no longer exists in the view.  You need to ensure that the identifiers remain constant between the two types of data

As I see your gif, when you swipe up the list, viewModel will loadMore data and set isLoadingMore is true so it cause body of historySection to be rerendered. In historySection you use an if statement to conditionally render so everytime isLoadingMore or isLoading is toggle list of history and skeletonView will be also destroy and create again.
My suggestion is you should put SkeletonHistorySectionView in overlay so the list will not be recreate when loading state change.
private var historySection: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        ForEach(groupedItems, id: \.key) { date, items in
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text(viewModel.dateFormatter.string(from: date))
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .padding(.leading)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .padding(.top)

                ForEach(items) { item in
                    HistoryRow(item: item, dateFormatter: viewModel.dateFormatter, timeFormatter: viewModel.timeFormatter, categoryDictionary: categoryDictionary, accountDictionary: accountDictionary, viewModel: viewModel)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            selectedItem = item
                            showingDetailSheet.toggle()
                        }
                        .swipeActions {
                            Button {
                               //TEST
                            } label: {
                                Label("TEST.", systemImage: "pencil")
                            }
                            .tint(.accentColor)
                        }
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 8)
            }
        }
    }
    .overlay {
        if viewModel.isLoading || viewModel.isLoadingMore {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(0..<3, id: \.self) { _ in
                    SkeletonHistorySectionView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


I fix it, just remove viewModel.isLoadingMore from here if viewModel.isLoading || viewModel.isLoadingMore {
